Distinguishing light sources with STM32 ADC and fast fourier transform
I want to identify if there are other light sources present at the same time as a 5 kHz 50% duty cycle PWM LED is on (this is arbitrary and it can be modulated at a different frequency). I have an ISL76671 light sensor that is connected to the ADC of an STM32. I'm using a timer with ADC DMA to sample with the ADC at 50 kHz. Then I'm using the CMSIS-DSP library to take the fast fourier transform of the ADC data with the goal of "removing" the 5 kHz component so I can see if other light sources are present. It isn't working and the FFT bin for 5 kHz is not distinguishable in magnitude from other bins. I connected my scope to the light sensor output, and this is what I see with the 5 kHz LED on in a dark room:

This is the LED on in a room with other light sources present:

I see the expected spikes every 200 us that correspond to the 5 kHz PWM rising edges, but I'm not sure if it's even possible to determine if other light sources are present from the ADC data. Should an FFT be able to do this? If not, is there a better method?
This is from the ISL76671 light sensor datasheet:


research IR television remote controls

Please look at the response time and rise/fall times of the output. Have you done the math if it is even possible to detect 5kHz with such a slow sensor?

@jsotola They are ICs and do not have analog output for FFT. Researching IR TV remote controls will not help, something else needs to be researched.

DC offset for the first trace is 180 mV, while DC offset for second trace is 310 mV. The difference would seem to be the result of the added illumination.

I want this to be more robust of a method than testing the DC offset, because I'm planning to add more LEDs that will increase the DC offset, and I'm not sure if I can depend on other light sources increasing the DC offset more than the LEDs alone if they are very bright.

I added the ISL76671 electrical specs, and now that I think about it...I should probably lower the LED PWM frequency due to the rise/fall times and I will test that. But still not sure if this whole concept should work.

I changed the PWM frequency to 1 kHz, and I still don't see a distinctive large magnitude FFT bin at around that frequency. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if this method just doesn't work given what I'm trying to do.

What does the received signal look like at 1kHz? What circuit are you using for the sensor?

are you squaring the input data to compensate for the square-root response of the sensor?
